# Debug apk is working fine but signed apk not working properly

Tags: android

The debug apk seems to be working properly but when I sign the apk, the navigation drawer doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: have you had your proguard enabled?

Comment: can you elaborate more?

Comment: Also can you share gradle buildTypes part as well of your app module?

Answer (score 0):

I also have faced like this problem in my case I follow :
You need to use debug keystore with password = "android". You can find your debug keystore in the .android folder. Example : C:\Users\shoeb.android